# how to send taskId to the table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, routes

I have file attachment form and in this form I need send $task->id to the file table.

this is file form action,

```
action=" route('projects.files', 'taskId'=>$task->id)">
```

and this is FileController methods,

```
private function saveUploads(Request $request, $fileUrl, $id,$taskId)
    {
        $file = new File;
        $file->file_name  =    $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->file_url   = $fileUrl;
        $file->project_id = $id;
        $file->task_id = $taskId;
        $file->save();
        }
```

and routes is this,

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}', [
     'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadAttachments',
     'as'   => 'projects.files',
     'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

but when I submit data to the table task_id row data values is like this,

```
route('projects.files', 'tasks'=>$task->id)
```

how can I send project id instead above values?

Comment: i am not understand your problem? can you explain better @John

Comment: ok my task_id row in files table saving data is not like project_is 1,2,3,4,5 it is allways saving with this values **route('projects.files', 'tasks'=>$task->id)**

Comment: unfortunately its still unclear to me :(

Comment: have you tried my answer @John

Comment: ok thing is this, in my controller i have following table column **task_id** it is send $taskId variable data. My taskId is like this 1,2,3,56,58 etc... but $taskId is carring allways following values to the colums **route('projects.files', 'tasks'=>$task->id)**

Comment: how can correct My route **route('projects.files', 'tasks'=>$task->id)**

Comment: `action=" route('projects.files', 'taskId'=>$task->id)">` this is just text, it doesn't get parsed by PHP ... that is literally the text you write, there is no PHP there.

Comment: @John even if that wasn't just 'text' and was actually in a PHP block, that isn't valid PHP       `route('projects.files', 'tasks' => $task->id)`

Comment: can you give me correct way to my route @lagbox

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#urls-for-named-routes  ... the docs is where all of this stuff is shown and explained, this is the first place to look

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your problem. If i understand some how.. you are looking for this kind of:-

```
<form action="{{url('projects/'.$id.'/tasks/'.$task->id)}}" >  $id i.e is your project_id
</form>
```

Hope it will help or explain your problem in better way

Comment: generate following error **Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\John\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php)**

Comment: add your taskid where i add $task->id